# How to disable the libreoffice macro feature, system-wide?

Tags: security, libreoffice

There are two `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/registry/*.xcd` settings, each should suffice:

```
org.openoffice.Office.Misc/Security/Scripting/DisableMacroExecution=true
org.openoffice.Office.Misc/Security/Scripting/MacroSecurityLevel=3
```

After applying those, a macro from a loaded text document results in:

```
An attempt was made to execute a macro.
For security reasons, macro support is disabled.
```

However, macro support is not disabled.
Adding a macro containing `shell "xterm"` to the current document and executing that still presents a terminal window.

**Which options *really* disable the macro feature?**

Is there a way to just not install the feature, instead of attempting to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what this excerpt from their site says but, in summary, it says that's not possible and can only be done per document.

> Options to disable macros are meant in LibreOffice for user's security, not for restricting what the user can do. It that regards, the macros in documents may be dangerous, while the macros in local libraries are under full control of the user (or admin), and thus are safe - which implies that from user's security point of view, there's no reason to disable them.

And it goes on to say:

> If you need means to disable all macros, you are welcome to come with an enhancement request, and even participate in the feature implementation (since I doubt that developers would be interested in the implementation: those who need something are most likely to have motivation).

Please look at the thread [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/168331/completely-disabling-macros/).